# Merging cells and general exception warning

Tags: c#, excel

I'm sort of new to Excel add-in via C# (and new for all of this thing in generally), and I'm trying do some simple pretty two cells merging, without a little success. This is the code:

```
void DisplayFirstTitles(IEnumerable<string> titles,
       Action<string, Excel.Range> DisplayFunc)
{
   var excelApp = this.Application;
   // Add a new Excel workbook.
   excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
   excelApp.Visible = true;

   //cells merge in the first title
   excelApp.Range[excelApp.Cells[0, 7], excelApp.Cells[0, 8]].Merge();
}
```

There is no error on the error list, only the:

> 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'

jump on.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but here is another way using OpenXML: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc880096.aspx

Comment: `Cells[]` is 1-based, not zero-based....